# image (hot link) blocking when no referrer (also blocking my own domain)

Tags: .htaccess, referrer, hotlinking

I have been trying to work through this issue for months now, without any success.

I want to block a 3rd party site where my images are displayed at.  (thirdpartysite.com)*

However everything I have tried has never worked...

I believe the forum is NOT using a referrer in its image requests...  so using its domain name has never worked.

I have edited my .htaccess file to block non-referrers...  but not my own site/content is ALSO being redirected to the alt image.

How can I stop this 3rd party non-referrer forum from displaying my hosted images, BUT still allow my OWN domain (mydomain.com)* to display the images correctly/properly? (not not the re-direct image)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} =""
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png)$ https://some-other-domain/some-image.jpg [R,NC]
```

-works to block the 3rd party site (which I guess is not sending a referrer, because add that     specific domain to block has never worked)

-but also seems to block/redirect all images on MY SITE as well?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} =""
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain\.com(/)?.*$ 
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png)$ https://some-other-domain/some-image.jpg [R,NC]
```

- doesnt seem to change anything?  MY domain still shows the redirected image.. (but so does the 3rd party forum site now..finally)

I have tried a slew of other entries..  but nothing has effected the 3rd party site except this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} =""
```

I'd also like to add a list of exception site that CAN hot link, such Arduino.cc,...etc (but who knows if they too send referrer info or not? - havent looked into that far yet)

How can I block this 3rd party forum, that sends no referrer info... but NOT effect my own site?

Comment: If your site instructs clients not to send any referrer at all, then this will hardly be possible. And even if it allows “normal” sending of the referrer, don’t expect all clients to send one - privacy settings or browser extensions might still filter it out.

Comment: How can I ensure MY OWN site passes referrer header/info then?  How do I add images to my content/pages and ensure referrer data?

Comment: Normally this does not need to be specifically enabled; the usual case would be the opposite, that a site explicitly _disables_ it, using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy But even if that is not the case and your site does not specifically forbid sending any referrer at all, there is no guarantee your site visitor’s browsers will always send one.

Comment: Well apparently..it does?  Since when I load my own site.. the images -are- being replaced. And 'explicitly' using my domain in the .htaccess file has no effect to bypass it.

Comment: We don’t know the complete scope of your setup, so there is no telling whether this might have explicitly been disabled somewhere in the server configuration. But using your browser dev tools, you can go and _check_ whether your own page sends such a `Referrer-Policy` response header, and if so, with what value exactly.